# Which modules does a controller and a view include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a site/page where there is a clear list of all the modules that all the views and all the controllers include?

A list like the following:

A controller includes:

- Module A
- Module B
- and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

> Constants MODULES =   [ AbstractController::Layouts,
>   AbstractController::Translation, AbstractController::AssetPaths,
>   Helpers, HideActions, UrlFor, Redirecting, Rendering, Renderers::All,
>   ConditionalGet, RackDelegation, Caching, MimeResponds, ImplicitRender,
>   StrongParameters, Cookies, Flash, RequestForgeryProtection, ForceSSL,
>   Streaming, DataStreaming, RecordIdentifier,
>   HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods,
>   HttpAuthentication::Digest::ControllerMethods,
>   HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods, # Before callbacks
>   should also be executed the earliest as possible, so # also include
>   them at the bottom. AbstractController::Callbacks, # Append rescue at
>   the bottom to wrap as much as possible. Rescue, # Add instrumentations
>   hooks at the bottom, to ensure they instrument # all the methods
>   properly. Instrumentation, # Params wrapper should come before
>   instrumentation so they are # properly showed in logs ParamsWrapper ]

ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: So I don't understand, does it include the ActionDispatch module? because for that list I don't see it

Comment: The code is listed here and well commented, might be good to take a look around to see what pieces of the puzzle you're interested in finding? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f7dc7e9e9b4c0599217144d7c4489c56c9474a8e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L176